# prove the following function limit statement

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

> Let $f$ be monotone ascending (for every $x\le y, ( f(x) \le f(y))$ in the segment $(a,b)$
>
> prove that:
> $\lim_{x\to x_0^+} f(x) = \inf_{x>x_0} f(x)$

thats the question.

a hint i can use states: if every monotone subsequence of a sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$ so does $x_n$

i couldn't find a connection between the hint and the desired result,
any ideas?

Comment: For a sequence $x_n \to x_0$ with $x_n > x_0$ for all $n > 0$, consider the sequence $\bigl(f(x_n)\bigr)_{n > 0}$. Apply the hint to that sequence.

Comment: i already did that, but i couldnt reach any conclusion regarding the $\inf$ of the given set

Comment: If $x_n$ is monotonic, what does $f(x_n)$ converge to?

Comment: $f(x_0)$?, but that doesn't tie up the 2 sides of the statement

Comment: There's no assumption of continuity, so we don't know whether that converges to $f(x_0)$.

Comment: any chance of a full solution, i am really at a loss in this question

Comment: No full solution. But, if $x_n$ is monotonic, it's not so hard to prove that $\lim f(x_n) = \inf_{x > x_0} f(x)$.

Comment: its also not that easy, as i cant represent any of them, only prove that they are equal somhow...

Comment: Make a list. What do you know about the sequence $f(x_n)$?

Comment: 1) is monotone decending. 2)converges to $\lim_{x\to x_0^+} f(x)$

Comment: Right. That's a good start. Now you want to show that it converges to $\inf\limits_{x > x_0} f(x)$. So assume it didn't. Then - you know that the limit is not smaller than the infimum - there exists an $x_\ast > x_0$ and an $\varepsilon > 0$ with $f(x_\ast) + \varepsilon < f(x_n)$ for all $n$. Why is that impossible?